Dependabot global configuration for pirvate_registries
We currently use repositories that require authentication for container images/npm packages/python packages/maven packages. Dependabot runners run in a VM.
According to documentation, seems that there is a way to configure authentication.
Following that documentation, we are able to make dependabot work if and only if, we add this configuration in the particular git repository where that ./.github/dependabot.yml file is defined.
This approach, would make each and every repository to have to define such credentials. Sadly, this is very impractical and we are attempting to define this "globaly" but without success.
Our attempt so far, consisted in adding this configuration into the dependabot configuration files in the VM where the services are running.
Is there a way to achieve such "central/global" configuration so credentials to repositories that require authentication don't need to be defined in every dependabot.yml file accross all organizations within our github server?
Thank you,
